# Change visualization of indentation in text editor for \t

Tags: text-editors, indentation, visualization

Is it possible to change the way a `\t` indentation is displayed in a text editor? For example, in Atom, Notepad++ or Kate?

Most people use spaces as identation (e.g.: pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> once produces 2 spaces), but ideally one should be able to only use `\t` for indentation and the text editor should let the user choose how to display the `\t` (e.g., as 2 or 4 spaces). This would also solve conflicts when one of the developers prefers 2 spaces over 4, etc.

*To be clear*, what I want is to change the way `\t` are displayed in text editors. I'd like to change an option on the fly where I'd visualize a `\t` as equal in length to 4 spaces, or 5 spaces, or n spaces.

I couldn't find any information about this option, only about making <kbd>TAB</kbd> produce spaces instead of `\t`, like in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-can-i-customize-the-tab-to-space-conversion-factor

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, this is specific to each text editor.  I don't understand because these settings were easy to find for me.  For instance, ***in notepad++*** go to 'settings'->'Language'->'Tab settings' (on the right).  You can select the number of spaces a tab will visually produce and opt to have actual spaces vs visual ones.  I use ***UltraEdit*** and it also has this feature+ but also lets me see '>>' to know it is a REAL tab if I choose so. ***Kate*** Configure->Editing->Indentation.  ***Atom***.. dunno (refuse to install).  Let me know if I am missing the point.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I love you! Yes, that's what I was looking for. I swear I couldn't find it before. For Kate, just a heads-up: you need to uncheck "Autodetect indentation" and, although I clicked on "apply" and "ok", the new settings only worked after I restarted Kate. Also related: https://superuser.com/questions/1567247/kate-editor-indentation-in-python

Comment: Nice! :) Glad it worked out for you.